# How to replace dots to commas and commas to dots in js

Tags: javascript, replace, format

I have a simple question, I would like to replace dots to commas and commas to dots in a string, example:

```
var example1 = "10.499,99" // What I have
var result1 = "10,499.49" // What I need

var example2 = "99.999.999.999,99" // What I have
var result2 = "99,999,999,999.99" // What I need
```

I already tried to use this replace:

```
value.replace(/,/g, '.')
```

But it only changes all commas to dots.

Any idea ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the variant of the `replaceAll` function that takes a function as the second parameter. Use it to replace all occurrences of either dot or comma. The function will choose to replace dots with commas and commas with dots.

```js
function switchDotsAndCommas(s) {

  function switcher(match) {
    // Switch dot with comma and vice versa
    return (match == ',') ? '.' : ',';
  }

  // Replace all occurrences of either dot or comma.
  // Use function switcher to decide what to replace them with.
  return s.replaceAll(/\.|\,/g, switcher);
}


console.log(switchDotsAndCommas('10.499,99'));
console.log(switchDotsAndCommas('99,999,999,999.99'));
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't do it at the same time. If you use replace function to change it from dot(.) -> comma(,) you will get your new string where a comma is replaced by a dot. But when you again try to do vice versa every comma will be replaced with a dot.

So what you can do is Replace the comma with a different string/symbol something like `replace(/,/g , "__")` then replace the dots with the same expression you are using above `replace(/\./g, ',')` and that replace those new string/(__) in our example to dot(.) `replace(/__/g, '.')`

`var example2 = "99.999.999.999,99"`
`example2.replace(/,/g , "__").replace(/\./g, ',').replace(/__/g, '.')` //output : '99,999,999,999.99'

Happy Coding

Answer (score -1):

Use

```
value.replace(".", ",");
```

Comment: Then you end up with `"99,999.999.999,99"`...

Answer (score -1):

```
value.replace(".",",")
```

Comment: This is the same as [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71603644/1364007) which was posted about an hour earlier.